# How to Upload a local word docx file on server using javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-word, xmlhttprequest, ms-office, office-js

I am developing a word add-in, in which i need to send the current modified document on server as .docx file, i will create a api to upload the current document on server (if needed).

Please guide me, how i can get the current document from word and upload on server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use `Office.context.document.getFileAsync(...)`.

See http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync for more info.

Copying one of the samples from that page:

```
function getDocumentAsCompressed() {
    Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 65536 /*64 KB*/ }, 
        function (result) {
            if (result.status == "succeeded") {
                // If the getFileAsync call succeeded, then
                // result.value will return a valid File Object.
                var myFile = result.value;
                var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
                var slicesReceived = 0, gotAllSlices = true, docdataSlices = [];
                app.showNotification("File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount);

                // Get the file slices.
                getSliceAsync(myFile, 0, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
            }
            else {
                app.showNotification("Error:", result.error.message);
            }
    });
}

function getSliceAsync(file, nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived) {
    file.getSliceAsync(nextSlice, function (sliceResult) {
        if (sliceResult.status == "succeeded") {
            if (!gotAllSlices) { // Failed to get all slices, no need to continue.
                return;
            }

            // Got one slice, store it in a temporary array.
            // (Or you can do something else, such as
            // send it to a third-party server.)
            docdataSlices[sliceResult.value.index] = sliceResult.value.data;
            if (++slicesReceived == sliceCount) {
               // All slices have been received.
               file.closeAsync();
               onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices);
            }
            else {
                getSliceAsync(file, ++nextSlice, sliceCount, gotAllSlices, docdataSlices, slicesReceived);
            }
        }
            else {
                gotAllSlices = false;
                file.closeAsync();
                app.showNotification("getSliceAsync Error:", sliceResult.error.message);
            }
    });
}

function onGotAllSlices(docdataSlices) {
    var docdata = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < docdataSlices.length; i++) {
        docdata = docdata.concat(docdataSlices[i]);
    }

    var fileContent = new String();
    for (var j = 0; j < docdata.length; j++) {
        fileContent += String.fromCharCode(docdata[j]);
    }

    // Now all the file content is stored in 'fileContent' variable,
    // you can do something with it, such as print, fax...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have followed the below link as i need to send the file on server :
See http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-powerpoint-or-word

I am able to get the document content in Slices and send using api, but I have no idea how to get slices on server side and compile each individual slice into a single .docx file and store on server.

Currently slices returns the data in base64. Please guide me to get the document slices on server side and create a single docx file.

Comment: You should have JS assemble it (which onGotAllSlices does). Then send it to the server as one big string, and use something like the OpenXml SDK to work with the file from there.

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky-Microsoft Could you please advice on [Word Web Addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410474/word-web-addin-getsliceasync-only-return-first-slice-of-data). Totally stuck.

Comment: @Asmi, I have left the Office Extensibility team some time ago, so I'm afraid there isn't anything I can help with. To my knowledge, StackOverflow is still the right place to get support, and the team should be monitoring it. If you haven't received a reply, maybe try asking the question again (though note, of course, that it's the holidays and many people are out on vacation; so you might have better luck in a week or so). Best of luck!