# Word Web-Addin: getSliceAsync() only return First Slice of data

Tags: javascript, office365, office-js, word-web-addins

I am developing an **office 365 word web addin**, wherein I need to upload the currently opened document to my server. For which I am trying to get the file data using following code.

The method **getSliceAsync()** is returning only first slice of data.
On debugging it gives *"Addin Error: Sorry, we had to restart because this addin wasn't responding"* while getting second slice.

I am using this link for reference : [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word][1]

Here is my code:

```
Office.context.document.getFileAsync(Office.FileType.Compressed, { sliceSize: 65536 }, function (result) {
    if (result.status == "succeeded") {
        // If the getFileAsync call succeeded, then result.value will return a valid File Object
        var myFile = result.value;
        var filename1 = myFile.name;
        console.log(filename1);
        var sliceCount = myFile.sliceCount;
        var slicesReceived = 0, isAllSlicesSuccess = true, docdataSlices = [];
        // document.getElementById("result").innerText = "File size:" + myFile.size + "#Slices: " + sliceCount;
        console.log(" File size:" + myFile.size + " #Slices: " + sliceCount, "");
   makeProgress(20);

        // Iterate over the file slices
        for (var i = 0; i < sliceCount && isAllSlicesSuccess; i++) {
            
            var diffPercent = ((i / sliceCount) * 100);
            
           
            myFile.getSliceAsync(i, function (sliceResult) {
                if (sliceResult.status == "succeeded") {
                    if (!isAllSlicesSuccess) { // Some slice has failed to get, no need to continue
                        console.log("Error", "One slice failed to get");

                        return;
                        console.log(sliceResult);
                    }
                    console.log('sliceResult', sliceResult);
                    console.log("Success", "i: " + i);
                    console.log("++slicesReceived  ",slicesReceived );
                    console.log(" sliceCount",sliceCount );
                    console.log("++slicesReceived == sliceCount",slicesReceived == sliceCount);

                    // One chunk was got, store it in a temporal array


                         //  ++slicesReceived;
                    // or you can do something with the chunk, such as sent it to a third party server
                    docdataSlices[sliceResult.value.index] = sliceResult.value.data;
                    if (++slicesReceived == sliceCount) {
                        getAllSlicesTime = Date.now();
                        var performance = (getAllSlicesTime - startTime) / 1000.0;

                        console.log("Success", "All slices has been get, Seconds: " + performance);

                        // All slices have been received
                        myFile.closeAsync(function (closeRes) {
                            if (closeRes.status == "succeeded") {
                                console.log("Close Success", "Success");
                               // DUClick();
                                
                            }
                            else {
                                console.log("Close Error", closeRes.error.message);
                            }
                        });
                        onGetAllSlicesSucceeded(docdataSlices, false);
                           
                    }
                }
                else {
                    isAllSlicesSuccess = false;
                    myFile.closeAsync(function (closeRes) {
                        if (closeRes.status == "succeeded") {
                            console.log("Close Success", "Success");
                           // DUClick();
                        }
                        else {
                            console.log("Close Error", closeRes.error.message);
                        }
                    });

                    console.log("Get Slice Error:", sliceResult.error.message);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        getFileTime = Date.now();
        var performance = (getFileTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
        console.log('Get File Error:', "Seconds: " + performance + " " + result.error.message);
    }
});
```

Please suggest! Thanks in advance!
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/get-the-whole-document-from-an-add-in-for-word

Comment: @JuanBalmori Could you please see this!