# Are outlook 365 web addin using EWS supposed to wok with regular outlook.com accounts?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have created an **outlook 365 web addin** using **EWS**. It required me to create a developer account for outlook 365 on web. Addin is working fine as expected on all outlook 365 accounts.

Does this addin is specific to Outlook 365 accounts or it should be working with regular Outlook.com? My addin is not working with outlook.com; I just want to make sure before declaring it to the users that it works only with Outlook 365 accounts.

Please suggest!

Comment: In general, Outlook web addin should work with outlook.com account. Could you clarify what behavior or error you see with your addin in Outlook.com? If particular EWS APIs are failing, could you include info on the API and error?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Could you please suggest on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410474/word-web-addin-getsliceasync-only-return-first-slice-of-data) Thanks!