# Microsoft Validation test failed: 1100.7.3 Duplicate Offer

Tags: visual-studio, office-store, powerpoint-addins, excel-web-addins

I have created two office 365 web add-ins which uploads my office documents(.pptx and .xlsx) to our document management system.
When I am trying to publish both on Microsoft Appsource; I got this failed report stating

> Easy Identification
>
> 1100.7.3 Duplicate Offer Your offer is a duplicate of an offer you have previously submitted: DMS Addin For Excel. This offer will
> not be accepted for the Marketplace.

I am wondering how can I fix this? Can One single addin be capable of uploading powerpoint and excel documents ? If yes , please suggest any reference to sort it?

Comment: Yes, you can combine Excel and PowerPoint in one add-in. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#set-the-hosts-element

Comment: Thanks for Suggesting. When I am trying to deploy the manifest without specifying Hosts tag (Workbook, Documents etc.) ( tried in MS admin center as well as AppSource) . It gives Manifest failed Validation error. if I put Host Name="Workbook"  this back, then it gives no error.

Comment: There needs to be a host or hosts mentioned in the manifest. If multiple were mentioned it should be like the below example:
<Hosts>
  <Host Name="Workbook" />
  <Host Name="Document" />
</Hosts>

Comment: Thanks it worked! Also please suggest on this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410474/word-web-addin-getsliceasync-only-return-first-slice-of-data . The Addin working fine in Excel and PowerPoint but only in case of word it can only upload file upto 1 slice ( 4mb).